# Values from models from Database (Django)

Tags: python, sql, django, models

I have this model

```
class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

And into it, I have some data from an sql file:

```
INSERT INTO quest_type (type, value) VALUES ('Noun', '1');
INSERT INTO quest_type (type, value) VALUES ('Adjective', '2');
INSERT INTO quest_type (type, value) VALUES ('Duration', '3');
```

How do I access these values in the python shell? For example, if I know the type, how do I get the value (and vice verse)? I'm not sure how the syntax works.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds like you want to read the [`QuerySet API`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to get that with

`Type.objects.filter(type=typeImInterestedIn)`

A couple of things to be leary of:
-you probably want to avoid manually writing to a DB that you're using an ORM in. It just creates potential for mismatches.
-naming an object Type is little problematic since it's so close to the python native function type.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question how much about databases you understand, so I apologize if this answer is too basic for you (if so, please edit your question to include information about what actual database engine you're using and show some sample code trying to read from the database).

The SQL file you have is not the same as an SQL database.  It is a series of commands that will create records in an SQL database. First you must install and configure a database engine on your machine then "run" that .sql file so that the records are created in the database.

After you have an actual database, you will have to configure Django so that it knows what kind of SQL engine you're using and the name and location of the database.

Finally, once the database is created and Django configured to talk to the engine, you will write python code to instantiate an instance of the Type class, read a record from the database, and inspect the values.

Also, let me point out that `Type` is a really, really bad name for a class in any programming language, and `type` and `value` are both bad names for columns in SQL databases.

Comment: I think I understand all this. It's more about the syntax. Some of the other answers above should help out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python shell from django (python manage.py shell) firstly You have to import to your namespace your model, so type from my_app.models import Type.

Now if You want to get only one object from db syntax is:

```
result = Type.objects.get(type='your_query')
```

If you want to fetch more then one object syntax goes like this:

```
result = Type.objects.filter(type='your_query')
```

second method returns list instead of single object

To loop through list after using filter write:

```
for item in result:
    item.value #will print values from matched rows
```

Comment: So let's say result outputs '<Type: Type object>, <Type: Type object>' It found two after using filter. How do I access what these are instead of the just saying object?

Comment: result[0], result[1] like normal list items. To loop through list write: for item in results: # do sth

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/ good stuff and nicely written :)